# Grep a stream against a set of "correct" words?

Tags: grep

I feel like this is a very basic question but I cannot figure out how to best accomplish this: I have a couple of documents (written in Latex) and I would like to run the program `spell` on them to generate a list of spelling errors:

```
spell -n -o *.tex | sort -k2 | uniq >misspelt.txt
```

The problem of course is that there are some valid keywords that it thinks are spelt incorrectly, for example one such line from the file is:

```
...
/home/me/Documents/doc1.tex: documentclass
...
```

I was thinking if it would be possible to put words like `documentclass` into a file and incorporate that as part of the above command so that it is *not* counted as a misspelling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very unlikely to work. You can't just use a spell checker on something that isn't text. For instance, wouldn't it find \begin as a spelling error? Have you considered opening the files in a decent tex-aware editor and running the editor's spell check? Or perhaps compiling the file to PDF or any other format, copying the text from the compiled document and running your spell check on that?

Anyway, to do what you want, even though I doubt it will work as intended, you can just pass a file with the words to `grep` with `-v` so it will skip lines that match:

```
spell -n -o *.tex | sort -k2 | grep -vf keywords.txt | uniq >misspelt.txt
```

Comment: Thanks. Admittedly, this is more of an exercise than an actual use case because as you mentioned I would be using an actual spell checker.  `grep -vf` line was exactly what I was  looking for (having tried out stuff like `diff` and others...). I still think it could be useful in scripts and such.

Answer (score 3):

Use `detex(1)` to get rid of LaTeX commands (most of them, anyway) and run the result through your spellchecker.

As Terdon's answer says, you can't spell check non-text, at least not directly.
Check e.g. [`aspell(1)`](http://aspell.net) list of filters to apply before spellchecking, by `aspell dump filters`. It seems the command `aspell list` gives directly what you want.